# Windows Software to Mount Volume/Partition Image File

Tags: windows, partitioning, mount, disk-image, logical-drive

Last night I had a BSOD a couple of minutes after moving a file. After a reboot, I found that the file was gone (it was deleted from the source partition and not present on the destination).

I took an image of the source volume (ie from the Boot Sector to the last cluster of the partition). Then I wrote a program to extract the unused clusters from a disk and save them as files.

Some of the free clusters on the original volume have now been overwritten so I need to use the image to do my final extraction. That means I need some software that can mount a volume/partition image, but all of the image mounting software I can find can only mount disk images (ie from the MBR—the master partition table—on).

Does anyone know of (hopefully free) Windows software that can do this?

I’ve already tried (without success): **VirtualCloneDrive**, **DaemonTools**, **VirtualFloppyDrive** (and probably a couple of others I can’t think of). They all either nag that the file is no good, or try to mount it, resulting in a disk that Windows complains has an unknown/corrupt filesystem.

Thanks.

Comment: With the software that mounts an entire drive image, how does it handle multiple partitions within that image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OSFMount](http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html) is a free program that can mount disk images containing just a single partition or entire drives with multiple partitions. Unlike most of the other programs I have tried, this one is aware of disk-structures, so it can detect the contents of image and lets your select what you want mounted.

If the image contains a partition table, it will display the contained partitions and let you mount either the whole drive, or select a partition. If it contains just a single partition, it mounts it as is.

It also lets you decide what type the mounted drive will be (hard-drive, optical, floppy, auto).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try alcohol 120  and [magicDisc](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-history.htm)

Comment: Okay, I will try them.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use [Virtual CloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/download.html) (freeware) to mount .ISO, .CCD, .DVD, .IMG, .UDF and .BIN files.

[image]

via [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/mount-an-iso-image-in-windows-vista/)

Comment: Nope, that doesn’t work; it wants full-disk images, not just volume images. If I try to mount this with VCD, I get a disk that Windows cannot recognize (ie “unknown/corrupt filesystem”). I’ll add a list of software I’ve tried.